# Mean of this experiment

Tags: statistics

Let the following experience :

> Let $x=n_0\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Each step, $x$ has a $1/2$ probability of increasing by one and a
>   $1/2$ probability of decreasing by one.
>
> The goal is to determine the Mean of this experience for an
>   infinite number of steps.

If $x$ was varying over $\mathbb{Z}$ then it seems obvious to me that the Mean should be $n_0$. However, if we now limit $x$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (which implies that if $x$ is $0$ and is to decrease then it stays at $0$), what is the Mean of the experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have equal probability of moving +1 or -1 then there will be no stable distribution and so the mean is not defined.

[See here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257676/probability-distribution-for-the-position-of-a-biased-random-walker-on-the-posit)